# Как подставить буквенную часть к названию переменной?

Tags: c++, c

Как подставить буквенную часть к названию переменной? Есть строчка `fprintf(logfile,"         ");`, как подставить к `logfile` еще буквенную часть? Примерно вида `logfile_{}`, где `{}` это буквенная часть?

Comment: Вы хотите добавить к строке другую строку? Или получить из переменной другую переменную? :)

Comment: Ну к примеру вместо того, чтобы писать несколько разных строк, осуществить перебор logfile_1, logfile_2, logfile_3 и т.д

Comment: Вам нужны массивы (vector/array)

Comment: Никак. Имена переменных существуют только во время компиляции, а не во время выполнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добро пожаловать в чудесный мир препроцессора С и его возможностей кодогенерации. Общий пример, что можно сделать:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FUNC(NAME, NUMBER)  NAME ##_## NUMBER

void print_hello(void)
{
    puts("Hello world!");
}

int main(void)
{
    FUNC(print, hello)();

    return 0;
}
```

Обьяснение, что за черная магия. Препроцессор - очень мощная штука, с помощью него можно делать буквально что угодно (хоть писать плюсовые шаблоны. Больно, но можно). В данном случае используется банальная конкатенация строк - вместо `##` подставляются значения "аргументов", которые были переданы. То есть, в вашем случае, это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
// Some code...

#define VAR(NAME, NUMBER)  NAME ##_## NUMBER

// Some code...

fprintf(VAR(logfile, 1),"");
```

Такая конструкция после препроцессинга будет восприниматься компилятором как `fprintf(logfile_1,"");`. Только остается проблема - в рантайме (то есть во время выполнения программы) так сделать не получится. Только на этапе препроцессинга. В вашем вопросе не очень понятно, в какой момент вы собираетесь менять название переменной, но если не в момент выполнения - данное решение может вам помочь